# Conditional distribution function of one random variable given the sum of two

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am trying to solve the following exercise in Probability Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version).

Let X and Y be independent exponential random variables for some $\theta>0$. Compute $P[X \leq x | X+Y]$ for $x\geq0$.

My solution is based only on the definition of conditional expectation and in particular on this property: if $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]]$ for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is called a conditional expectation, where $X\in\mathcal{L}^1(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{A}$ are two $\sigma$-algebras.

Thus, for every $A\in \sigma(X+Y)$:

$\int_A \mathbb{1}_{X(\omega)\in[0,x]} d\mathbb{P}=\int_A\mathbb{1}_{X(\omega)\in[0,x]} d(\mathbb{P}\circ(X \times (X+Y))^{-1})=\int_A\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{t-y\in[0,x]} \theta e^{-\theta(t-y)}\theta e^{-\theta y}dydt=\int_A \int_{t-x}^{t} \theta^2e^{-\theta t}dydt=\int_A \frac{x}{t} t\theta^2e^{-\theta t}dt = \int_A \frac{x}{T} d\mathbb{P}$.

So I conclude: $P[X \leq x | X+Y] = \frac{x}{X+Y}$.

In the second equality I obtained the density of $(X,T)$, where $T=X+Y$, in this way: $f_{X,T}(x,t)=f_{X,Y}(t-y,y)=f_X(t-y)f_Y(y)$ by the independence property.

Is this correct?

**Edit**

Taking in the comments made by @D Ford, if I define $T=X+Y$, then this is the correct chain of equalities:

$\int_A \mathbb{1}_{X\in[0,x]}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}= \\
\int_{T(A)}\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(X) d(\mathbb{P}\circ(X \times (X+Y))^{-1})=\\
\int_{T(A)}\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{t-y\in[0,x]} \theta e^{-\theta(t-y)}\theta e^{-\theta y}dydt=\\
\int_{T(A)} \int_{t-x}^{t} \theta^2e^{-\theta t}dydt=\\
\int_{T(A)} \frac{x}{t} t\theta^2e^{-\theta t}dt = \\
\int_A \frac{x}{T} d\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: In the first equality, you're integrating the function $\mathbb 1_{X(\omega) \in [0,x]}$ (which, by the way, I think is better written as $\omega \mapsto \mathbb 1_{X \in [0,x]}(\omega)$) over the event $A$ on both sides of the equality; but the first integral uses the measure $\mathbb P$, and the second uses the measure $\mathbb P \circ (X \times (X+Y))^{-1}$. These measures are defined on different measure spaces ($\mathbb P$ on the probability space $\Omega$ and $\mathbb P \circ (X \times (X+Y))^{-1}$ on $\mathbb R^2$), so something's not right in that equality.

Comment: I thought that the two random variables are defined on the same space $\Omega$ and so their transformations. Something like "I am measuring the $\omega$s that, when mapped, are in the product between $X$ and $X+Y$".

Comment: The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are both defined on $\Omega$, but the transformed measures $\mathbb P \circ X^{-1}$ and $\mathbb P\circ Y^{-1}$ are not. If $E$ is a metric space and $Z$ is a random variable with values in $E$ (i.e. a measurable map $Z : \Omega \to E$), e.g., $E = \mathbb R^2$ and $Z = X \times (X+Y)$, then $\mathbb P \circ Z^{-1}$ is defined as $(\mathbb P \circ Z^{-1})(A) = \mathbb P[Z^{-1}(A)]$. This only makes sense if $A \subset E$, not if $A \subset \Omega$.

Comment: There is, however, a way to do what you're suggesting, i.e., measure those $\omega \in \Omega$ that are mapped via (a composition of) random variables to a metric space $E$. See Theorem 4.10 in Klenke.

Comment: How would you correct my first equality with the composition of random variables that you are suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at Theorem 4.10 in Klenke. You want to make sure that the variable(s) that you're integrating with respect to agree both with the measure and in the set you're integrating over. (Notice you're also integrating with respect to $t$, over the set $A$, even though $A \subset \Omega$ and $t \in \mathbb R$). In the case of a random variable $Z$ with values in $E$, if you want to consider an event $A \in \sigma(Z)$, $A \subset \Omega$, you could for example say: $$\mathbb E[Z \mathbb 1_A] = \int_A Z d\mathbb P = \int_{Z(A)} z (\mathbb P \circ Z^{-1})(dz).$$

Comment: In the above, note $z \in Z(A)$, and the measure $P \circ Z^{-1}$ is defined on $E \ni z$, so the domain and the measure agree.

Comment: I made an edit with your corrections, I hope they are right now.

Comment: I made a new answer. Perhaps you’ll find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

> In the second equality I obtained the density of (X,T), where T=X+Y, in this way: $f_{X,T}(x,t)=f_{X,Y}(t−y,y)=f_X(t−y)f_Y(y)$ by the independence property.
>
> Is this correct?

No. You have the right idea, but you begin with a function of $x$ and $t$, so should *not* end with a function of $t$ and $y$.

Rather:

$$\begin{align}f_{X,T}(x,t)&=f_{X,Y}(x,t-x)\\&=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(t-x)\\&= \theta^2\mathrm e^{-\theta x}\mathrm e^{-\theta (t-x)}\mathbf 1_{0\leq x}\mathbf 1_{0\leq t-x}\\&=\theta^2\mathrm e^{-\theta t}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq t}\end{align}$$

---

And similarly we might obtain the same result:.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leq x\mid X+Y=t) &=\dfrac{\int_0^x f_{X,Y}(s,t-s)\,\mathrm d s}{\int_0^t f_{X,Y}(s,t-s)\,\mathrm d s}\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\lt t}+\mathbf 1_{t\leq x}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\theta^2\mathrm e^{-\theta t}\int_0^x \mathrm ds }{\theta^2\mathrm e^{-\theta t}\int_0^t \mathrm ds}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\lt t}+\mathbf 1_{t\leq x}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{x}{t}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq x<t}+\mathbf 1_{t\leq x}\end{align}$$

> So I conclude: $P[X≤x\mid X+Y]=x/(X+Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution to this problem. If we know $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous (as we suspect the joint density of $X$ and $X+Y$ to be), then we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
g(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \int_0^x \int_0^y g(s,t) \, ds \, dt. 
$$
In this case, to find the joint density of $X$ and $X+Y$, we first observe:
$$
\mathbb 1_{\{X \leq x\} \cap \{X+Y \leq z\}} = \mathbb 1_{\{X \leq x \} \cap \{Y \leq z - X\}} = \mathbb 1_{A(x,z)}(X,Y),
$$
where $A(x,z) = \{(s,t) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 \leq s \leq x, 0 \leq z \leq y-s\}$.
So we compute:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P \left[ \{X \leq x\} \cap \{X+Y \leq z\}\right] &= \int \mathbb 1_{A(x,z)}(X,Y) \, d\mathbb P \\
&= \int_{A(x,z)} d\left(\mathbb P \circ(X \times Y)^{-1}\right) \\
&= \int_0^x \int_0^{z-s} \theta^2 e^{-\theta(s+t)} \, dt \, ds \\
&= 1 - e^{-\theta x} - \theta x e^{-\theta z}.
\end{align*}
Differentiating this with respect to $x$ and $z$, and noting $X, Y \geq 0$ and $\mathbb P[\{X > z\} \cap \{X+Y \leq z\}] = 0$, we find that the joint density $f$ of $X$ and $X+Y$ is
$$
f(x,z) = \theta^2 e^{-\theta z} \mathbb 1_{[x,\infty)}(z) \mathbb 1_{[0,\infty)}(x).
$$
This joint density, along with part (i) of this exercise, can be used to compute both $\mathbf E[X|X+Y]$ and $\mathbf P[X \leq x | X+Y]$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues in your new chain of equalities that should be addressed, and I felt it was probably better to articulate them as an answer rather than post a comment.

> [T]his is the correct chain of equalities:
> $\int_A \mathbb{1}_{X\in[0,x]}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}= \\
> \int_{T(A)}\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(X) d(\mathbb{P}\circ(X \times (X+Y))^{-1})=\\
> \int_{T(A)}\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{t-y\in[0,x]} \theta e^{-\theta(t-y)}\theta e^{-\theta y}dydt=\\
> \int_{T(A)} \int_{t-x}^{t} \theta^2e^{-\theta t}dydt=\\
> \int_{T(A)} \frac{x}{t} t\theta^2e^{-\theta t}dt = \\
> \int_A \frac{x}{T} d\mathbb{P}$.

I agree with the second, third, and fourth. The fifth is correct, but needs some justification: why do you know the density of $T = X+Y$ is $t\theta^2 e^{-\theta t}$? That’s essentially what the final equality is saying. The second works after making the change of variables $X = t-y$ and using what we know about the joint density of $(X, X+Y)$.

The first equality, however, still needs some work.

The integral $\int_E f \, d\mu$ has three objects: a measure space $E$, a measure $\mu$ on $E$, and a (real or complex)-valued function $f$ defined on $E$. Your first integral is $\int_A \mathbb 1_{X \in [0,x]}(\omega) d\mathbb P$; here, $E = A$, $\mu=\mathbb P$ (a measure defined on $A$), and $f = \mathbb 1_{X \in [0,x]}$ (a function defined on $A$). So this works. (Although usually if it can be avoided we don’t include the independent variable in the integrand, $\omega$ in your case.)

Now consider your second integral: $\int_{T(A)} \mathbb 1_{[0,x]}(X) d(\mathbb P(X \times (X+Y))^{-1})$. Here, the space is $E = T(A)$ (a subset of $\mathbb R$), the function is $f = \mathbb 1_{[0,x]}(X) = \mathbb 1_{[0,x]} \circ X$ (a composition of functions whose domain is $\Omega$, not $\mathbb R$), and the measure is $\mu = P \circ (X \times (X+Y))^{-1}$. This measure is defined on $\mathbb R^2$, because the codomain of the function $X \times (X+Y)$ is $\mathbb R^2$, so if $B$ is a subset, then $\mathbb P \circ (X \times (X+Y))^{-1}(B) = \mathbb P((X \times (X+Y))^{-1}(B))$; but this expression only makes sense if $\mathbb B \subset \mathbb R^2$. So the measure isn’t defined on $T(A)$ (a subset of $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^2$).

Now, the integral transformation law tells us that if $E$ and $F$ are measurable spaces, $\mu$ a measure on $E$, $T : E\to F$ a measurable map, and $f : F \to \mathbb R$ a real-valued function, then $$\int_E f \circ T d\mu = \int_F f d(\mu \circ T^{-1}).$$ This makes sense: $f \circ T$ is defined on $E$, so the first integral works, and $\mu \circ T^{-1}$ is a measure on $F$, so the second integral works. For example, if $Z$ is a random variable and $B \subset \mathbb R$ is measurable, then:
$$
\mathbb P[Z \in B] = \int \mathbb 1_{Z \in B} d\mathbb P = \int \mathbb 1_B(Z) d\mathbb P = \int \mathbb 1_B d(\mathbb P \circ Z^{-1}).
$$

Applying this to the first of your edited equalities, you start with $\int_A \mathbb 1_{X \in [0,x]} d\mathbb P$. If you want to integrate over $T(A)$, you would need to express the function $\mathbb 1_{X \in[0,x]}$ as a composition $f \circ T$ in the first integral to do that, for some function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, but it’s not clear to me how you would do that. Instead, you want to integrate over $(X \times T)(A) = X(A) \times T(A)$, which it looks like you ultimately end up doing anyways. Then, we could say:
$$
\mathbb 1_{X \in [0,x]} = \mathbb 1_{[0,x] \times [0,\infty)}(X, X+Y)
$$
Or, better yet, if $A \in \sigma(X+Y)$, then $A = (X+Y)^{-1}(B)$ for some $B \in \mathbb R$, so:
$$
\mathbb 1_A \mathbb 1_{X \in [0,x]} = \mathbb 1_{[0,x] \times B}(X, X+Y)
$$
Implicitly, this last thing is what you end up doing anyways. But again, you want to justify your use of those densities.

Comment: Like you said, I implicitly tried to measure the set of $\omega$ that satisfied the constraint on $X$ given some information about $X+Y$. I did a mess with the notation! I’ll read carefully e post an edit. For the densities I think I could justify them through the convolution. I don’t quite understand your observation about the use of this too much “powerful” technique. I thought I was only using the definition of conditional expected value. Anyway, thank you for the time spent with me! I appreciate since I am studying on my own these topics after work!

Comment: You’re absolutely correct; my comment about the more powerful technique was ill-thought. But I’m glad I was able to help clarify some of the notation issues with the integrals :)